# Não consigo logar no phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Nesse momento eu tô estudando serviços de nuvem de arquivos compartilhados como OwnCloud e Pydio.

Eu estou utilizando o Debian 9 como máquina. Instalei o xampp nele. Entrei normalmente nas configurações do phpmyadmin e fui colocar senha no usuário root.

Quando se entra lá na página tem o seguinte:

```
root :: 127.0.0.1

root :: 1

root :: localhost  <-- Eu abri esse e coloquei uma senha e o hashing da senha eu coloquei mysql 4.1+ e gerei o password.
```

depois eu fui na pasta do phpmyadmin e editei o arquivo `config.inc.php` e deixei do jeito que tá na imagem.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois disso eu salvei e quando vou entrar no phpmyadmin aparece isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como corrigir isso?

Answer (score 1):

Depois de alterar o arquivo de configuração, tente limpar os `cookies` e reiniciar o *browser*. Acesse novamente e vê se funciona.

Eu estou tentando configurar o Apache 2.4 no XAMPP para Windows e sempre tenho que fazer isso, se não são mostrados sempre dados desatualizados na minha página.

Tente reiniciar o `phpmyadmin` também.

Comment: Não deu certo. Permanece do mesmo jeito.

Comment: Tentou setar "AllowNoPasswordRoot" para `true`?

Comment: Se eu colocar true, eu estou dizendo que o root não tem senha.